# iOS, iPhone, iPad: is slow loading a good strategy to avoid memory crashes?

Tags: ios, ipad, memory, crash, timing

This question is a follow-on to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142402/ipad1-memory-mystery-with-my-texture-intensive-game-app).

I have a game on the App Store that, only rarely, crashes when loading on iPad1. The game is resource-intensive and does indeed load up several large textures on start-up. A restart of the device makes the problem go away. I haven't been able to repro this on my own devices, so I only have reports/data from a few customers.

(Let's assume for the sake of this question that (a) my app does indeed need to load all of the textures it loads, and (b) I'm not doing anything dumb like leaking something or not disposing of something as early as I could.)

The question is: Does it make sense to try to load the textures more slowly?

The thinking is that when my app is loading up textures when it starts, it begins using up memory quickly. If there are other apps that are resident and are using up memory that I need, the OS will start sending notifications to those apps that they should release memory. But my understanding is that it gives those apps a couple seconds to free up memory and/or quit, and during those seconds my app continues to aggressively load textures. So the thought is that the OS panics, and needs to kill something right away, and kills my app. But perhaps if I had loaded things up more slowly, the other apps would have had time to respond to the memory warnings and free things up, and everything would have worked out.

Does that line of thought make sense? Do you have experience with that approach helping to avoid crashes?

Comment: have you tried using instruments to track your memory usage?  if your memory usage is spiking heavily on load, then that's probably what's causing the crash.   i had a similar problem in an app that only occurred when it was on an iPad 1 running iOS 3.2 (no virtual memory!) and staggering the loads over time a bit did seem to help.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an idea of how you staggered the load? Like, how much were you loading per second (or whatever time unit), and how much did you slow it down to get it to behave better?

Comment: My approach wasn't that sophisticated - I just stripped down what I was calling in the viewDidLoad method to the absolute bare minimum I needed to get the user started and then called the rest of what I needed from an additional method after a slight delay.  I.e  `[self performSelector:@selector(yourDelayedLoadMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.2];`  Or something similar at the end of your viewDidLoad method.  My delay was brief, but it definitely seemed to help on some devices.

Answer (score 1):

One issue about loading everything at the very beginning: depending on when you do it, you can take too long to launch, and the watchdog timer will kill your app for being unresponsive. (It didn't sound like this is what's happening to you, but it's a theoretical possibility. Easy to spot the 0x8badf00d in crash logs.)

Comment: That's a good point. Do you know how long you get to start processing events before it decides you're not responsive? Does it vary by OS or device type? And indeed it seems like there could be interaction here with the memory manager: I load up some resources and it sends me (and other running apps) memory warnings, but I'm too busy loading more resources to respond to them.

Comment: I believe it’s explicitly not documented so that it can be tuned as needed. The “iOS Performance and Power Optimization with Instruments” talk at this year’s WWDC did give some numbers, which depend on what the system is doing (Launch is different from Resume, so if you empty your cache when you go to the background and then reload, you might get burned). The Launch timer is easy to avoid — don’t load until after you’ve launched.